# Select the closing tag in HTML with Intellij/PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I can't seem to find a keybind or an ability to select the closing tag of an element. Say im sitting on the opening `div` tag i wanna be able to select the closing tag to be able to change this to say a `section` or `header` for example.

I can use `Add Select for Next Occurrence` but if there are some `div` inside the the element i want to change then obviously it selects them as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to navigate to opening tag and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to navigate to the closing tag.

By the way, there is an easier way to rename a tag. If you have the opening tag selected you can just hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (rename refactoring) to change the tag.

Other way is to change the opening tag (let's say from div to section), hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select *Rename end tag 'div' to 'section'*).

---

**Update**: IntelliJ 14.1 also introduced new [simultaneous tag edit feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/simultaneous-tag-editing-in-intellij-idea-14-1/) which simplifies tag renaming even further.

Comment: I refactoring is exactly what i was after i use this all the time no idea why i didn't think to try it with this. Thank you!

Comment: Why did they make Ctrl + [ a shortcut?  Isn't that usually a more ergonomic version of ESC?